# Could not find method in parent or ancestor context

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I've been dealing with this problem for awhile and have looked at all the relevant questions I could find, such as: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567192/could-not-find-method-addcontactview-in-a-parent-or-ancestor-context), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446524/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-find-method-view-in-a-parent-or-anc), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140197/error-could-not-find-method-submitregisterview-in-a-parent-or-ancestor-contex). Could you help me correct this error? It's the only one being thrown by the logcat.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method playPauseMusic(View) in a parent or
ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'playPause'
```

Relevant code:

**radio.java**

```
package com.example.jacob.wutk;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.IOException;

public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Called when the user touches the button */

    public void playPauseMusic (View view, final ImageButton playPause) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; // your URL here
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
                } else {
                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause1);
                }
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    }
}
```

**activity_radio.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context="com.example.jacob.wutk.radio">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_mic1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip">
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/playPause"
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:onClick="playPauseMusic"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:src="@drawable/play1"/>
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That's everything in `radio_activity`

Comment: can i see the code where you are calling this method `playPauseMusic` ?? **called when user touches the button** can i see that button code ??

Comment: It's in `radio_activity`. It's the ImageButton.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Defining `onClick` in `xml` means you need to define it for a particular view here is `ImageButton` you can not have two arguments in that method.

Your error is also saying that **Could not find method playPauseMusic(View)** means compiler needs a *public method with single parameter `View`*, whereas you were having two parameters: `View` & `ImageButton`.

This is the reason why you where getting that error. Just remove one argument from the method and it will work.

Do it like this :

```java
public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Called when the user touches the button */

    public void playPauseMusic (View playPause) {
        String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; // your URL here
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
             mediaPlayer.pause();
             ((ImageButton)playPause).setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
        } else {
            ((ImageButton)playPause).setImageResource(R.drawable.pause1);
        }
        
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    }
}
```

One more thing writing `android:onClick="playPauseMusic"` means the method `playPauseMusic` will be called on Button click so you have already defined a button click so **no need to define it inside the method** by `playPause.setOnClickListener` so I have removed that code.

Answer (score 6):

Your code possibly should start with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
}
```

You're specifying onClick in xml

```
android:onClick="playPauseMusic"
```

So, the method works, you've got inner onClicks too. If they are some views.

You gotta initialize and get it from the xml in code, for ex-

If you have ImageButton in xml, whose id is "playPause"

```
ImageButton playPause; //Declare it here if you wanna use it in all other places in the class or outside of your class

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);

    playPause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.playPause);

    playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //OnCLick Stuff
        }
    });
}
```

In Your case, you've got onClick attribute in xml and another onCLick in code. You Use one.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered but I hope this will help someone like me in the future. I was having this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test1, PID: 6892
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method btnClickStartThread(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'btnStartThread1'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:447)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:405)
```

After struggling a lot I got it fixed by going to `layouts` and I realized I had two layouts:

1. `activity_main.xml`
2. `activity_main.xml (v21)`

My changes were just reflecting on one and the app was loading other version of layout.

As suggested here
[Android Studio not deploying changes to app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791588/5737774)