# MyApps get crashed but cannot find the solution,

Tags: android, android-studio

//HERE IS MY LOGCAT, cannot find the solution

```
09-17 07:56:55.115 6180-6180/com.example.safwan.mymonitoring E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.safwan.mymonitoring, PID: 6180
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method BSave(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'BSave'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

// RecordActivity.java, where the code for insert data into MYSQL

public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button BSave;
EditText TFincubatorid, TFTotal, TFDate;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_record);
    //initializa alert dialoog
    //builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordActivity.this);

    //initialize by text field
    TFincubatorid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFincubatorid);
    TFTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFTotal);
    TFDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFDate);
    //initialize btn by id
    BSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BSave);

    // click function
    BSave.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this); //click button

    // pop up loading dialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

}
```

//Button function, where the user clicks to save into database
already wondering 3 days

```
public void BSave (View view)
{
    final String incubatorid = TFincubatorid.getText().toString().trim();
    final String total = TFTotal.getText().toString().trim();
    final String calender = TFDate.getText().toString().trim();

    //validation
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(incubatorid))
    {
        TFincubatorid.setError("Fill in incubator id");
        TFincubatorid.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(total))
    {
        TFTotal.setError("Fill in total succesfull egg hatch");
        TFTotal.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(calender))
    {
        TFDate.setError("Choose date after 21 days");
       TFDate.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    class Record extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RecordActivity.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(constant.TFincubatorid, incubatorid);
            params.put(constant.TFTotal, total);
            params.put(constant.Calender, calender);


            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(constant.ROOT_URLRECORD, params);
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("You have been successfully save the data."))
            {
                Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent (RecordActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    Record reg = new Record();
    reg.execute();
}
```

}

//Fragment_Record.xml, already put android:onclick="BSave"

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorGrey"
tools:context="com.example.mymonitoring.RecordActivity">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chickeneggbroken"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TFincubatorid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/element_outline"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_format_list_numbered_black_24dp"
        android:hint="No siri of incubator"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TFTotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/element_outline"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        android:hint="Total eggs succesfull egg "
         />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TFDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Select Date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calender_black_24dp"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BSave"
        android:onClick="BSave"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@drawable/button_black"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

//This is my fragment that extends RecordActivity.java, it contain calender view

```
public class RecordFragment extends Fragment{


// calender view code
private static final String TAG = "RecordFragment";
private TextView mDisplayDate;
private TextView DisplayDate;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

public RecordFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false);

    mDisplayDate  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TFDate);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String date = "Date :"+String.valueOf(year) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear) +"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                    mDisplayDate.setText(date);
                   // tfDate.setText(date);
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);
            datePicker.show();
        }
    });
    mDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: date:" + year + "/" + month+ "/" +dayOfMonth);
        }
    };
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: never set onClick listeners in XML. That is the source of your error.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392359/could-not-find-method-in-parent-or-ancestor-context

Comment: show your xml code aslo

Comment: all the code above, do help me i going to die if it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle a button click, 
First is by implementing Callback `OnClickListener` and other by setting `onClick` attribute to the button in XML.

First method goes like this,

```
Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BSave);

// Register click listener
BSave.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**you must make your activity or fragment implement `OnClickListener`**.

For doing it the other way, add this line to your button,`android:onClick="BSsave"` and the method you have written will work.

**NOTE : In this case the method to be called `onClick` must be public and should have a `View` parameter like shown below:**

```
public void yourMethodName(View view) {
    // do something here...
    // you can check which button is clicked by checking the id
    if (view.getId() == R.id.myButton1) {
        // Button1 clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: both i already tried but the button either will no work or my app get crashed,

Comment: i have tried first method, but my app crashed, for the second method also i tried but my button cannot be clicked

Comment: i wondering now, when i created the RecordActivity,java it never extend or link to the Record_Fragment.xml and RecordFragment.java. so do you think this is might be the error cause

Comment: Just remove this line,  
    `BSave.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this); //click button`

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand this comment of yours, "i wondering now, when i created the RecordActivity,java it never extend or link to the Record_Fragment.xml and RecordFragment.java. so do you think this is might be the error cause "