# How to start a Media Player from MainActivity when i press button from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, media-player, android-button

I have the buttons oferton, atrape, smiders, imbecil, billetes, and tonto, 
what I want to do for Example:
I want to press the button oferton from the fragment Frag1 and then start the media player momo1 that is in the MainActivity
I know this is wrong, but I want to know how to start a Media Player from MainActivity when i press button from a Fragment.

This is MainActivity

```
package com.example.mauri.miapp;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public MediaPlayer momo1;
  public MediaPlayer momo2;
  public MediaPlayer momo3;
  public MediaPlayer momo4;
  public MediaPlayer momo5;
  public MediaPlayer momo6;
  Frag1 f1;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     f1 = new Frag1();
     momo1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oferton);
     momo2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.atrape);
     momo3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.smiders);
     momo4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.imbecil);
     momo5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.billetes);
     momo6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tonto);
     android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
     manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.LayoutContenedor, f1).commit();
  }

}
```

and this is my Fragment: Frag1

```
package com.example.mauri.miapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    public Frag1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onCreateView");
        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);

        ImageButton oferton = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_oferton);
        ImageButton atrape = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_atrape);
        ImageButton smiders = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_smiders);
        ImageButton imbecil = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_imbecil);
        ImageButton billetes = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_billetes);
        ImageButton tonto = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_tonto);

\\This is bad, but is a Example for what i whant to do
        oferton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo1.seekTo(0);
                momo1.start();
            }
        });
        atrape.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo2.seekTo(0);
                momo2.start();
            }
        });
        smiders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo3.seekTo(0);
                momo3.start();
            }
        });
        imbecil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo4.seekTo(0);
                momo4.start();
            }
        });
        billetes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo5.seekTo(0);
                momo5.start();
            }
        });
        tonto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                momo6.seekTo(0);
                momo6.start();
            }
        });

        return vista;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onCreate");

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onAttach");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onActivityCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onViewStateRestored");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "Destroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.i("fragmento01", "onDetach");
    }

}
```

Comment: use interface..

Comment: You can try Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: either use interface , or send event from fragment to activity , and inside that fragment play your media player.

Comment: what is a Broadcast Receiver?, and how i can use a interface for this, please leave me and answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method in activity which starts media player and call this method from your fragment like this,

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).playMediaPlayer();
```

Comment: i want to call the method when i press a button, how i can do ?

Comment: @MauricioChaila use this answer inside your onClick

Comment: Add an `OnClickListener` to your button and in the `onClick` method of the listener write this line.  If you want to know how to do that,  check this ans.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52364335/8663757

Comment: ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playMediaPlayer(); i want to call this method when im press a button but i cant, how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

**create a method in Main Activity**

```
    public void playSong(String runninsong) {          
           if(player.isplaying()){
             player.stop();
            player.release();}
           int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(runningsong, "raw", 
             getPackageName());
               player.prepare();
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

**and in the fragment on click of button**

first create an object of mainactivity

```
MainActivity mainActivity




 oferton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {     
mainActivity = new MainActivity();                          
                mainActivity.playSong("oferton"); //You need to pass ID of the audio file
            }
        });
```

Comment: playSong method accepts int and u r passing a string value from fragment.

Comment: they dont leave me to create a static void

Comment: You can do it wihout static method but then you would have to create a new object of mainactivity everytime

Comment: @MauricioChaila i have edited my answer try it and tell me what happens

Comment: @KhanStan99 thank you for spotting error i have edited my answer

Comment: @KevienKurien, thank you so much, now only have error in  player.prepare();

Comment: player.prepare(); gives me IQException

Comment: @MauricioChaila try 'calling player.release()' in MainActivity below player.reset , if still gives error try removing player.reset and inserting player.release()

Answer (score 0):

**My Main Activity Public Function:**

```
public void showToastMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**And this is how i use in a fragment:**

```
assert (getActivity()) != null;
((SXBaseDrawerActivity) getActivity()).showToastMessage(string);
```

**In You case, OnClick button you can do like this:**

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.yout_btn);
btn.OnClickViewCompensation((v) -> {
    assert (getActivity()) != null;
((SXBaseDrawerActivity) getActivity()).showToastMessage(string);
});
```

**Note:** I used toast method for example, You can use your own function.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i dont understand how i can do for start a MediaPlayer  in MainActivity from fragment onClick

Comment: @MauricioChaila you can check Kevin's answers for the MediaPlayer method and how to start it.